# Member 'object.equals(object?, object?' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; quality it with a name instead on string in list removal c#?

Tags: c#, string, list

I've got a list, called genres, and I'm trying to remove a genre the user will add to it, regardless of case. I've specified a string variable called "genre" further up in the code, but I'm getting CS0176 when I try to do a RemoveAll() command. Here's the bit of code that's playing up:

```cs
        [Command("RemoveGenre")]
        [Description("Remove a genre from the list of genres")]
        public async Task Remove(CommandContext ctx, string genre)
        {
            if (genres.Contains(genre, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var message = await ctx.RespondAsync($"Are you sure " + genre + " is correct?");

                var yes = DiscordEmoji.FromName(ctx.Client, ":white_check_mark:");
                var no = DiscordEmoji.FromName(ctx.Client, ":x:");

                await message.CreateReactionAsync(yes);
                await message.CreateReactionAsync(no);

                var interactivity = ctx.Client.GetInteractivity();

                var reactionResult = await interactivity.WaitForReactionAsync(x => x.Message == message, ctx.User, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).ConfigureAwait(false);

                while (!reactionResult.TimedOut)
                {
                    if (reactionResult.Result.Emoji == yes)
                    {
                        genres.RemoveAll(n => n.Equals(genre, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                        await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Removed " + genre + " from list. Genre list now contains " + genres.Count.ToString() + " genres").ConfigureAwait(false);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (reactionResult.Result.Emoji == no)
                    {
                        await Cancel(ctx);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Please use the emojis provided. Cancelled.");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync("This genre doesn't exist in the list! Nothing has been removed.").ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
```

The bit that's got the error is the "n.Equals" part, and I'm not sure why. Additionally, genres of a list of strings.

If anybody could help me, that would be really good. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What´s the definition of "genre"? Is it static, maybe?

Comment: It's not static, is one of the variables I've set up in the async task. "public async Task Remove(CommandContext ctx, string genre)".

Comment: @Komsur: This is why it helps to show a [mcve] - so we don't need to guess this sort of thing... Likewise we don't know the type of `genres`.

Comment: It's a list of strings.

Comment: @Komsur: But again, if you'd shown that in a [mcve], we wouldn't have had to ask. What you've got now is better (in that it shows `genre`) but it's still incomplete, and it's also not minimal. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for advice on how to ask really good questions. (It takes some time, but honestly it's worth it in the long run.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
if (reactionResult.Result.Emoji == yes)
{
     genres.RemoveAll(n => string.Equals(n, genre, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
     await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Removed " + genre + " from list. Genre list now contains " + genres.Count.ToString() + " genres").ConfigureAwait(false);
                    break;
}
```

Check the example on .net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lsq3y1)

The compiles thinks it is using the `object.Equals` to compare `genre` with the `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` values, instead of what you expect it to do.

Comment: This causes CS1503: "cannot convert from System.StringComparer to System.StringComparison".

Comment: True, I fixed it and it should work fine now. You need to use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. There is also a net fiddle to check it.

Comment: Yes, that's fixed it! I'll accept this as the answer. Thanks!